# Shell script to check and re-run program

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash script to check if my python script miner_nbeats.py is currently running and if not, then re-run because sometimes my python script gets killed due to out of memory error. So I have this bash script below, which works and executed the program at the beginning. However, I noticed that it’s not really re-running the python script after it gets killed.

```
while true; do

    if /bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py" | grep -v $$ >/dev/null; then
        echo "script running"
    else
        echo "script not running"
        tmux new-session \; send-keys "source activate python310 && cd /home/putsncalls23/directory && python miner_nbeats.py” Enter
    fi
    
    Sleep 300
done
```

So I checked the htop program and I believe that the system is detecting the associated pid from running the bash script. I’m relatively new to bash scripting and would greatly appreciate any help with regards to this.